# Jenkins: Keep older build running if new build fails to deploy

Tags: jenkins

I'm new to jenkins. 
For that sake I installed the latest version of jenkins i.e. 1.632 on my ubuntu and deployed a war using post build actions in the configuration part. That worked fine for me.

Then I changed a few things in the build making sure that it fails when deployed and it effectively did and I'm not able to access the application die to deployment failure.

But I'm curious here, I have heard that in case of a build failure jenkins makes sure that the previous build remains deployed so that the application is always up and running. Please clarify if I'm wrong or doing anything wrong in my deployment steps.

I did searched a lot about this but couldn't find a valuable answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Haven't done much with the deploy plugin but it states this in the docs

> Now when you trigger this job you can enter the build number (or use
>   any other available selector) to select which build to redeploy.

So you can set up a build on failure which will redeploy the last stable version. Here is also an example how to get the last stable build number:

```
http://<JENKINS>/job/<JOB_NAME>/lastStableBuild/buildNumber
```